# Web Audio APIを利用していて、再生できないm4a音源がある

Tags: javascript, web-audio

Google Chrome上で動く(Firefoxでは動かない)簡単なWebアプリを作ってます。

FileAPIで取得したオーディオファイル(wav, m4aなど)の中身を渡して、再生する`playSound`という関数があるのですが、たまに再生できない`m4a`音源があります。

コードは以下のような感じです。(余計な処理をのぞいたもの)

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new window.AudioContext();
var source;
function playSound(arraybuffer) {
    context.decodeAudioData(arraybuffer, function (buf) {
        this.source = context.createBufferSource();
        this.source.connect(context.destination);
        this.source.buffer = buf;
        this.source.start(0);
    });
}

// 関数の呼び出し部
function playFile(file) {
    var freader = new FileReader();
    freader.onload = function (e) {
        playSound(e.target.result);
    };
    freader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

`m4p`が再生できないのであれば`DRM`のせいだろうと思うのですが、`m4a`で再生できない音源があるのはなぜでしょうか。

コードの問題なのか、音源の問題なのか(`iTunes`上で再生できます。別のアカウントが管理する`Mac`上でも再生できます)、何か良い解決案があればお願いします。

尚、再生できない音源についてですが

- ファイル名は半角スペースあり英数字(半角スペースを消しても改善なし)
- サイズは約25MB
- 長さは約3分
- 925kbps(?!)

です。

Comment: ファイルが大きいために、
1つのファイルに対して `onload` が複数回呼ばれて、
そのたびに `playSound()` で…ってことはありませんかね?
仮にそうだとすれば `onload` では貯めるだけにして、
`onloadend` でまとめて `playSound()`
という手が使えるかもしれません。

Comment: 25MBで3分というのはなかなかサイズが大きいと思う(128kbpsで5分で5MB程度ぐらいじゃなかったですっけ)のですが、ビットレートはいくつなんでしょうか？

Comment: @KoRoNさん ありがとうございます。なるほどです。確かにファイルがちょっと大きいようですね。onloadend()を試してみます（検証は夜になりそうです)

Comment: @fliedonionさん ありがとうございます。ビットレートを追加しました。ちょっと普通ではないファイルですね。その辺から再確認してみます。

Comment: @3100さん ぱっと検索した感じ、925kbpsって動画のビットレートではよく使われるみたいですね。ひょっとすると動画ファイルなのかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

信頼度が足りずコメントを書けないのでこちらに書かせて頂きます。

ビットレートから察するに、もしかしてAACではなく可逆圧縮のApple Losslessのファイルではないでしょうか？　Apple Losslessも拡張子`m4a`で保存されます。

iTunesで再生できるのであれば、iTunes上でファイルのプロパティを開けば「ファイル」タブでコーデックを確認することができます。

もしAACでないのであれば、そもそもChromeでは再生できないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: Apple Losslessという選択肢を全く考えておりませんでした。Losslessを動かすには`ALAC.js`などが別途必要みたいですね。。

Answer (score 2):

AACのプロファイルではないですか？

http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

AAC audio codec (Main only, not AAC-LC, AAC-SSR, HE-AAC)

Answer (score 1):

どのタイミングでエラーがでているのか分かっていますか？
onLoadの際に、エラーが取得できるので、ファイルフォーマットの問題であれば、それをチェックすると分かるのではないでしょうか。